# how can i take backup of mysql database tables

Tags: mysql, database

i want to move mysql database tables which resides in one computer to another computer. how can i create dump file as we created in Oracle ?
i m using exp command but not working.

Comment: [Backingup using PHP MyAdmin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database)

Comment: use mysqldump command

Comment: [Backup using MySQL Administrator](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/mysql_gui_tools.htm#backup_restore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqldump`.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> <db_name> > <filename>.sql
```

To import, create empty database named `<db_name>`, thena -

```
mysql -u <username> -p<password> <db_name> < <filename>.sql
```

To export all databases -

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> --all-databases > <filename>.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> -h <hostname> <dbname> <tablename> > filename.sql
```

Now you may need to take the dump of just the schema. For example you use a command called like.

```
mysql> show create table tablename;
```

this will give you the query that created the table. Now for some reason you need to take schema dump of all the tables inside you database/databases you may use -d option like this

```
mysqldump -d -u <username> -p<password> -h <hostname> <dbname> > filename.sql
```

The `-d` option means "without data".
Now you have full dump without the data and just the schema.